# vb.net data storage options?

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, save

We are currently building a application thats main function is : parameticly building 3D drawing models.

The GOAL is that employees with no drawing program installed can still provide the parameters save them. Then notify the drafting engineer so he can check the parameters and run the main function of this application.

(The result of running this function will not result in a 100% finished model the drafting engineer should still have in some cases 100+ hours work on it. Should you be wondering why not send the data to the server and let it run by itself.)

Further there are some text fields that need to be saved, but there is no data explosion.

Currently we had in mind creating a txt file for each project and save comma seperated strings into it, and load it back afterworths.

BUT there are also other options.. I know we could use .xml for saving, or SQL technique.

What are the pro's and con's for these options, and are there other options that we should explore?

If anyone knows some good reference documents that we could read that would be great.

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here because of being too wide and accepting many different solutions (= opinions). From your description, I understand that the datasets will not be too big; in that case, you might rely on files (higher portability). The simpler is the format, the quicker the reading/writing processes. Although up to some thousands records you shouldn't notice any difference among alternatives; even the most complex/resource-consuming ones (e.g., MS Excel/Word). In any case, all this is very basic and the person in charge of building the application should know about it already.

Comment: CSV is not the way to go.  It is the hardest method to parse.  I like using an excel workbook as a front end database.  I would use oledb method to read data into vb.net, or open xml.   Don't use the Interop interface it is extremely slow.

Comment: (See why this is off-topic?) @jdweng Can you please explain the reasons for your statements? For example, why "CSV is not the way to go"? Do you know anything about the datasets? Why concluding such a thing? All the options have positive/negative points and no sensible person can deliver absolute conclusions without even knowing the conditions. But I can also play at the absolute truths nonsense: CSV (or a plain txt file) should always be the first choice; the lightest, simplest and fastest; not requiring special knowledge/libraries and very portable. (Proper) databases for big datasets.

Comment: **One of the best plain text data formats around is YAML.** While CSV has no master-detail flexibility and XML is too machine--oriented (difficult to read/write for humans etc.), YAML is similar to JSON (JSON is subset of YAML), but YAML has excellent readability and greater flexibility. Check [YAML at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) or [here](http://yamlserializer.codeplex.com/) is one of parsers.  [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) has even better support in .NET than YAML, but it is somewhat less flexible. Anyway, check both and consider.

Comment: @varocarbas – Alvaro, no problem. Let the OP show alternatives CSV/YAML/XML and probably we both understand the choice will be on them depending on their data model and other requirements. They will need to do some study anyway.

Comment: @miroxlav (sorry I don't know your name) showing alternatives is fine. Concluding that one alternative is undoubtedly better than any other one (without giving any reason and, what is much worse, without even understanding the exact conditions) is misleading and not-helpful. This was the whole point of my original comment to jdweng. In your comment for example, you are bolding the statement "One of the best plain text data formats around is YAML" (+ why others are worse). Is this showing alternatives?

Comment: @varocarbas – and are there alternatives? I've professionally spent tenths of hours with CSV's, same time with XML's and custom tree-structure formats. Seeing OP's question (engineering industry) it is likely they will need tree data. And as of tree data, YAML is superior to anything around! (Do you know better alternative? Please show me... I'm striving to know efficient data formats.) So there are my reasons.

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks actually this is precisely how things should be done (supported with your own experience or any other thing, defining the conditions, etc.). From my experience, I would assume that the information contained in the file should be as simple as possible (i.e., no person will use it, just the applications) and thus the best approach would be text file. I say CSV because the columns will be divided with commas, but always treated as a text file (e.g., created, read and updated via StreamWriter/Reader). I see things from the app point of view; you from the user point of view.

Comment: CSV is not very robust.  Excel screws up CSV royally.  Converts integers to dates, CSV you have to parse the fields with code.  XML has tags to identify items which is more robust.  Using oledb with excel is nice because data is automatically converted to DataTables.

Comment: I know My question is very unspecific, sorry for that! Further, read ability is not really important for the user, the application should show evrything in a structured way. After doing Some thinking it might seem better to do Search jobs in a database? I forgot to mention this at first but it would-be conveniant to Search old projects that have simular data for the reuse of info.

Answer (score 1):

Off topic but after discussion in comments, I am posting a quick reply:

- CSV – tabular data only

  - pros: easy parsing; can be edited in Excel
  - cons: you need more than one CSV file for representing master–detail relationships
- YAML – tree-oriented data

  - pros: intuitive, with superior readability
  - cons: parser support is not very wide
- JSON - tree-oriented data

  - pros: great parser support
  - cons: same purpose as YAML, but less readable
- XML – tree-oriented data

  - pros: great support for parsing and automated content validation
  - cons: users need to train their eye to read it and train their skills to write it
- SQL data tables – tabular data only

  - pros: great support for data operations
  - cons: often need application with UI to access, best result but most work

Check Wikipedia for introduction to first four. There are also links to home page of each standard where you can find links to parsers etc.

Comment: As explained in my last comment, you see the problem in a very restricted way; by assuming that users will have to read it. The OP hasn't said anything. My assumption would be right the contrary.